# Running Powershell(x86) from WScript.Shell

Tags: vba, powershell, wscript.shell

I have the following statement I'd like to execute in Powershell(x86) using VBA:

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted -force; 
$DBPath = "U:\Data\Distribution\Common\Dist\Weekly Hours Entry\DC Master Production DB V2\Packing Slip Generation\PackingSlipGeneratorBE.accdb"; 
$SQL = "SELECT VENDOR, PackingSlipID, EntryNumber, ShipDate, TrackingNumber, RA, EntryDate FROM tblPackingSlipLog WHERE EntryNumber>1000001 AND EntryNumber<1000011;";
$Output = "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.csv";
$Con= New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;
$con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= $DBpath";
$ConCommand= $Con.CreateCommand();$ConCommand.CommandText = $SQL;
$OAdapt = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $ConCommand;
$DS = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet;$OAdapt.Fill($DS);
export-csv -InputObject $DS.Tables[0] -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation -force;$Con.Close()
```

I am able to run just the Powershell(x86) in Powershell(x86) with no problem. Also, if I run the `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` part in command prompt and then the powershell part separately, it also works as intended. However, when I try running them together it doesn't work.

The calling VBA function: `GetPackingSlipData ("WHERE EntryNumber>1000001 AND EntryNumber<1000011")`

```
Function GetPackingSlipData(strSQL_WhereClause As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wsShell As Object
    
    Dim strPowerShellCommand As String
    Dim strOutputFile As String
    strOutputFile = GetDocuments & "\Test.csv"
    
    Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strPowerShellCommand = "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted -force; $DBPath = ""U:\Data\Distribution\Common\Dist\Weekly Hours Entry\DC Master Production DB V2\Packing Slip Generation\PackingSlipGeneratorBE.accdb""; " & _
                           "$SQL = ""SELECT VENDOR, PackingSlipID, EntryNumber, ShipDate, TrackingNumber, RA, EntryDate FROM tblPackingSlipLog " & strSQL_WhereClause & ";"";" & _
                           "$Output = """ & strOutputFile & """;" & _
                           "$Con= New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;$con.ConnectionString = ""Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= $DBpath"";" & _
                           "$ConCommand= $Con.CreateCommand();$ConCommand.CommandText = $SQL;" & _
                           "$OAdapt = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $ConCommand;" & _
                           "$DS = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet;$OAdapt.Fill($DS);" & _
                           "export-csv -InputObject $DS.Tables[0] -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation -force;$Con.Close()"
                           
    Debug.Print strPowerShellCommand
    
    Call wsShell.Run(strPowerShellCommand, 1, True)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        GetPackingSlipData = "Error: " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description
    Else
        GetPackingSlipData = strOutputFile
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

The command that gets printed:

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted -force; $DBPath = "U:\Data\Distribution\Common\Dist\Weekly Hours Entry\DC Master Production DB V2\Packing Slip Generation\PackingSlipGeneratorBE.accdb"; $SQL = "SELECT VENDOR, PackingSlipID, EntryNumber, ShipDate, TrackingNumber, RA, EntryDate FROM tblPackingSlipLog WHERE EntryNumber>1000001 AND EntryNumber<1000011;";$Output = "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.csv";$Con= New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;$con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= $DBpath";$ConCommand= $Con.CreateCommand();$ConCommand.CommandText = $SQL;$OAdapt = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $ConCommand;$DS = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet;$OAdapt.Fill($DS);export-csv -InputObject $DS.Tables[0] -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation -force;$Con.Close()
```

Comment: How are you launching it? There's no VBA...

Comment: Updated to include my calling code.